# React VS Code external scripts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, codepen

I'm using VS Code with React and I wanted to try this: codepen.io/andystent/pen/GRgjBdJ?editors=0010

In the settings at codepen appear 5 links to 5 external scripts which this pen is using so it can work. I downloaded the JS from this pen, saved it in a file and imported it in /src folder, but I do not know how and where to add those 5 external scripts so my script could work. Can you please help me? How can I add external scripts to my react project? And where to add them (index.html/App.js/index.js etc)?

Comment: You should look for these libraries on [npmjs](https://www.npmjs.com/) and use react versions of them if possible. An even better solution would be to properly create that slider as React app (and not use jQuery for instance)

Comment: Thanks, but I do not know how to do that, I'm a newbie at React. Could you please point me in the right direction? Then I'll do the research myself and try to code it.